# Hive and User Defined Function's

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a question on UDF's on Hive.
When I am using an UDF in a hive query, does it process the data in a MapReduce manner? For instance when I use the function avg. Does Hive convert the function in mapReduce Jobs?
Bests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases a Hive query will be translated to an map/reduce job (the exceptions are things like SELECT * on a HBase table). Average (avg) is a built in aggregate function and not a UDF but this Hive will process both in a map/reduce job.

Note that future versions of Hive would probably improve on this (see for example this [post on Hive Stinger initiative](http://hortonworks.com/blog/100x-faster-hive/)) but as mentioned above, currently it is mostly m/r